# Python: SOAP API not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, xml, api, soap, python-requests

I'm trying to use SOAP API of movildata.com to get last location of a vehicle, using IMEI and api key, here is my code:

```
import requests

api_key = 'xxxxxxxxx'
imei = 'xxxxxxxxx'

request = """<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<soap12: Envelope xmlns: xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns: xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns: soap12 = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12: Body>
    <getLastLocation xmlns = "http://ws.movildata.com/ws/wsUsers">
      <apikey> {0} </ apikey>
      <IMEI> {1} </ IMEI>
    </ getLastLocation>
  </ soap12: Body>
</ soap12: Envelope>
""".format(api_key, imei)

encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')

headers = {"Host":"ws.movildata.com",
            "Content-Type": "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Length":str(len(encoded_request))
            }

response = requests.post(url='https://ws.movildata.com/wsUsers.asmx?op=getLastLocation', 
                         headers=headers,
                         data=encoded_request
                         )

print(response.content)
print(response.status_code)
```

This returns XML response and HTTP status code 500

> soap:ReceiverEl servidor no puede procesar la solicitud. ---> Un
>   nombre no puede empezar con el car\xc3\xa1cter \' \', valor
>   hexadecimal 0x20. L\xc3\xadnea 2, posici\xc3\xb3n
>   9.

I translated from spanish and it says something similar to

> The server can not process the request. --- & gt; A name can not start
>   with the character ' ';

I made sure the there wasn't any unnecessary empty space in `request` but that didn't seem to change anything, any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen few errors of your XML formatting.
Try correcting them as said below. If still getting the error, comment down below.

First in the namespace declarations in `<soap12:` element, you can not have spaces between the `xmlns` and `xsi`.

correct all of them: `xmlns:xsi`, `xmlns:xsd` and `xmlns:soap12`

In `<getLastLocation`, you just had `xmlns`, without any variable name. Some parsers may not accept it. Give some dummy name (ex: `xmlns:abc`).

In the closing elements, you have space between `</` and element name.

Correct all below:

```
</getLastLocation>
```

`</soap12:Body>` (Also remove space between `:` and `Body`)

`</soap12:Envelope>` (Also remove space between `:` and `Envelope`)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, something strange occured, the initial `request` string I had was copied from https://ws.movildata.com/wsUsers.asmx?op=getLastLocation with all the formatting errors you pointed out, now it is fixed.